# Error entre java - jdbc oralce, resultset null

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Actualmente tengo un código que ejecuta una consulta a una base de datos en oracle la cual devuelve cerca de 200.000 resultados y luego recorro el resultset para armar un csv.

El problema que tengo es que en algunas ocasiones, algunos valores de una columna del resultset llegan `null`, pero cuando ejecuto la consulta por aparte dichos valores no están `null`. Lo mas extraño es que en la fila donde aparecen los valores null también se modifica la información de otras columnas (es decir si la información debía salir `hola mundo` sale `mundohola`).

Si filtro la consulta para que traiga menos resultados entre ellos lo que está saliendo `null`, esta vez no llegan `null` dichos valores, ya se ha vuelto un dolor de cabeza este problema.

Adjunto el código que está creando el csv:

```
private ReporteBuilderVO generarCsvBySql(String sql) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    ReporteBuilderVO builderVO = new ReporteBuilderVO();
    Integer rowSize = 0;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream write = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        try (Connection connection = getJDBCConnection()) {
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                //System.out.println("size 
                resultSet.getFetchSize());
                resultSet.setFetchSize(300);
                ResultSetMetaData dataModel = resultSet.getMetaData();
                int columnCount = dataModel.getColumnCount();

                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                    buffer.append(dataModel.getColumnName(i));
                    if (i < columnCount) {
                        buffer.append(";");
                    }
                }
                buffer.append("\n");
                //System.out.println("Fila de títulos construida");
                write.write(buffer.toString().getBytes());

                while (resultSet.next()) {

                    rowSize++;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                        write.write(resultSet.getString(i) != null ? 
resultSet.getString(i).replaceAll("[\n\r]", " ").getBytes() : "".getBytes());

                        if (i < columnCount) {
                            write.write(";".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                        }
                    }
                    write.write("\n".getBytes("UTF-8"));
                }
            }
        }
        builderVO.setResultadoOutput(write);
        builderVO.setTotalFilas(rowSize);
        //System.out.println("rowSize "+rowSize);
    }
    //System.out.println("Saliendo de generarCsvBySql");
    return builderVO;
}
```

Si imprimo los `resultset.getString(i)` aparece `null`, pero al ejecutar la consulta ese dato no es `null`. Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar en este aspecto, o si hay alguna mejora que se le puede hacer a este método para evitar que pase esto.

PD. Algo que me parece pertinente aclarar es que el dato de la columna que está saliendo null, en realidad es un campo obligatorio, por ende, nunca es null y esta fue la razón del porqué nos enteramos del inconveniente.

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]

Comment: Por favor, trata de incluir un conjunto de datos de prueba como los que estás usando, de forma tal que el problema en tu pregunta pueda replicarse.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, no sé muy bien como generar una data de prueba sin utilizar información sensible de la base de datos (la cual no estoy autorizado a dar).

Comment: No sabemos cuál es el `sql` de entrada ni los datos. No sé muy bien cómo responder a la pregunta sin "adivinar" (la inversión de la cadena "holamundo" a "mundohola" dice que hay líos con el `sql` pero no sé cuáles puedan ser

Comment: @Fernando Guevara Ya solucionaste el problema

Comment: Hola Raul, aún no hemos logrado dar solución al inconveniente. Alfabravo, la consulta sql no creo creo que tenga el problema, dado que al aumentar los filtros para que se traiga una cantidad menor de datos, éstos salen bien, y cuando ejecuto la consulta en el sqldeveloper, por ejemplo, los datos salen correctamente, la duda que me queda es que dicha consulta se comporte algo diferente al ejecutarse con el driver jdbc de java, respecto a la forma en que se ejecute en el sqldeveloper.

Comment: Hola! Tal y como indicaba Alfabravo, había un comportamiento erratico en la forma como java mediante el JDBC ejecutaba la consulta, dicha consulta era de la forma Select * from ((select...) as col1,(select ...) as col2 from tabla where condiciones), se modificó la consulta para eliminar los selects internos y el problema desapareció.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como indicaba Alfabravo, había un comportamiento erratico en la forma como java mediante el JDBC ejecutaba la consulta, dicha consulta era de la forma:

```
  Select * from (
   select
    (select...) as col1,
    (select ...) as col2 
   from tabla where condiciones
  )
```

Se modificó la consulta para eliminar los selects internos y el problema desapareció.